# Where does Intellij deploy my war when i use tomcat plugin?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, web-deployment

I run Tomcat from Intellij (using plug-in).

Where is the content folder that my war is deployed?

It's not in my local Tomcat folder:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.4/libexec/webapps
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is in `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/<version>/libexec/webapps/ROOT/` because that is the only app that you are using and perhaps on deployment application context was chosen to be '/'.